# Conventional place to store ceritificates and keys in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: debian, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04

I am migrating a server I inherited; it has a signed certificate.

The server is a "LERP"-stack (Linux Nginx Rails Passenger). The previous maintainer stored the certificates under `/etc/nginx/`; I doubt this is the convential place to store them, in Ubuntu or Debian.

But where should I store them? I have:

```
example.com.crt
example.com.csr
example.com.key
SSL123_CA_Bundle.pem
```

nginx, running as www-data, [needs read-access](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) to these files.

I currently not running a mailserver or proxy server, but I would assume a the "preferred place" to store the certificates on a Debian or Ubuntu server would be somewhere where Dovecot or Squid and such, have access to the certs too; if they are implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nginx is the only thing requiring the certificates running on that box, I doesn't feel particularly wrong to me to keep the files in the /etc/nginx hierarchy.  Certainly, anyone interested can look at the configuration file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled to find the location of the cert and key.

If there are other services, Ubuntu should be providing an /etc/ssl hierarchy if you've installed certain packages:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/ssl
ca-certificates-java, openssl, ca-certificates: /etc/ssl
```